# Should I edit this question to be more generic?

Tags: discussion, editing, allowed-questions

I am referring to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/271875/145980).

The OP originally asks about purchasing and playing multiple copies of No Man's Sky, which is not currently released. (From what I understand of the rules of this site, "Speculation of... upcoming releases" is not an [acceptable topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

However, the real question itself is more of Steam question that happens to use No Man's Sky as an example. It can easily be generalized to any Steam game, as the current accepted answer also shows.

Should I edit the question to be more general ("Running the same game from two different Steam accounts", for example)? Or should I just downvote/closevote/leave it alone/move on?

I was thinking of changing the question by just taking out the No Man's Sky related text as follows:

> If my wife and I want to play a single Steam game off the same computer, at different times, would it be possible to:
>
> - Buy two copies off of one Steam account;
> - Buy one copy each under two Steam accounts. If this is the preferred option, can they both use the same installation location?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be general to Steam. I'd say edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ultimately, I agree](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/271875/3).

The question has been received well, compared to other questions regarding unreleased games. The only answer has been accepted, and is generic to steam games.

I had actually seen this question in the close queue, and made the generic changes you speak of, before seeing the post here, on meta.

Remember, if you can retain the intent of the question, and make subtle changes to remove an obvious close reason, **do it**.